# K nearest neighbor distance

Tags: java, knn

I am working on the kNN classification problem for school. What is the formula for calculating the distance from one x y coordinate to another x y coordinate? I just need the algebra, not the code.

Comment: "I need the algebra, not the code"... You realize this is a site basically revolving around code, right? There are other sites for math problems.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for Euclidean distance in two dimensions

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance#Two_dimensions